# Reading parameter while Windows Service is running

Tags: c#, parameters, arguments, windows-services, args

How can I check if there is an external parameter when my application is running and how can I start a new thread if there is an incoming parameter?

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    odbcConnection = new OdbcConnection(ConnectionString);
    odbcDataAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(QueryString, odbcConnection);
    new Thread(new ThreadStart(run)).Start();
}

protected override void OnStop()
{

}

public void run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            if (odbcConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                odbcConnection.Close();
                odbcConnection.Open();
            }

            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            odbcDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

            if (!Directory.Exists(Path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path);
            }

            using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(Path + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".xml"))
            {
                dataSet.WriteXml(fileStream);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        Thread.Sleep(300000);
    }
}
```

i don't really know what I should do I need to use a parameter for the first time and I need to do it on a running application

Comment: fwiw, creating connection and adapter objects to share for the lifetime of your app is [not good.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/398790/8057)

Comment: Also, if you're only gonna run every 5 minutes, this might actually be better as a scheduled task instead of a service.